# Auto Fill in a macro

Tags: excel, autofill, vba

Writing a Macro based on hours worked for employees. I am trying to use the macro to populate the hours based on the employee's # and hard code it to prevent getting a ref sign for managers that do not have the original files.  I recorded the macro and changed it to auto fill down to the last row  however it fills 6 lines after the amount of employees there are regardless of the number of rows of employees that week has. What am I doing wrong.

```
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -4).Range("A1:F1").Select
lastrow = Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveCell.Range("A1:F" & lastrow)
ActiveCell.Range("A1:F" & lastrow).Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's filling below where you expect it to end, it is likely 'lastrow' is incorrect (some hidden formatting or values may be present at the bottom of the sheet)

try using...

```
lastrow = Cells.Find("*", Range("A1"), xlValues, , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
```